# how to get data from single row by user id laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am new in laravel, i want to get single record of user by **user id** and display in Input value. please guide me

### Controller

```
public function profile(){

    $userdata = User::all();

    return view('pages/edit-profile')->with('userdata',$userdata);
}
```

### Route

```
Route::get('profile', 'PageController@profile_c');
```

### Form View

```html
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/edit_profile" method="post">
                    {{  csrf_field() }}
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">First name:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" value="Jane">
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Last name:</label>
     <div class="col-lg-8">
       <input class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName" type="text" value="Bishop">
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Display name:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
       <input class="form-control" name="displayName" id="displayName" type="text" value="Jane Bishop">
    </div>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email:</label>
     <div class="col-lg-8">
      <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" disabled type="email" value="janesemail@gmail.com">
     </div>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the user by their id

```
$user = User::find(id);
return view('pages/edit-profile', compact('user'));
```

If you know something else from the user that is unique like the user email

```
$user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
return view('pages/edit-profile', compact('user'));
```

In the form, if you are using blade

```
<input name="email" value={{ $user->email }} />
```

And more importantly, how to use ELoquent: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent